# Properties are initialized... Why the error "Cannot use instance member 'X' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self'

Tags: swift, xcode, initialization

I have initialized my properties birthdate and newHireDate.  Yet when I call these properties in an array I receive the following error for 'birthdate' and 'newHireDate' : "Cannot use instance member '(birthdate)/(newHireDate)' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available".

The same error is also given for functions/methods 'calcAge' and 'calcYearGroup'.  These are functions/methods and I don't understand why or how these can be initialized.

Here is my Model code:

```
struct Employee: Identifiable {
let id: String = UUID().uuidString
let age: Int
let yearGroup: Int

init(age: Int, yearGroup: Int) {
    self.age = age
    self.yearGroup = yearGroup
}
}
```

and my ViewModel code:

```
class ViewModelTwo: ObservableObject {

@Published var array: [Employee] = []
@Published var birthdate = Date()
@Published var newHireDate = Date()

init(birthdate: Date = Date(), newHireDate: Date = Date()) {
    self.birthdate = birthdate
    self.newHireDate = newHireDate
}
func calcAge(birthday: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let now = Date()
    let calcAge = calendar.components(.year, from: birthdate, to: now, options: [])
    let age = calcAge.year
    return age!
}
func calcYearGroup(hireDate: Date) -> Int {
    let calendar: NSCalendar! = NSCalendar(calendarIdentifier: .gregorian)
    let now = Date()
    let calcYearGroup = calendar.components(.year, from: hireDate, to: now, options: [])
    let yearGroup = calcYearGroup.year! + 1
    return yearGroup
}
static var employeeData: [Employee] = [
    Employee(age: calcAge(birthday: birthdate), yearGroup: calcYearGroup(hireDate: newHireDate))]
} //here is where the four errors appear: 'calcAge', 'birthdate', 'calcYearGroup' and 'newHireDate.'
```

Here is my EmployeeCardView:

```
struct EmployeeCardView: View {
let employee: Employee
var body: some View {
    HStack{
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Year \(employee.yearGroup)")
                .font(.headline)
            Label("\(employee.age)", systemImage: "person")
                .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                .font(.subheadline)
        }
    }
}
}

struct EmployeeCardView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var data = ViewModelTwo.employeeData[0]
static var previews: some View {
    EmployeeCardView(employee: data)
}
}
```

And here is my EmployeeView:

```
struct EmployeeView: View {
@StateObject var employeeViewModel: ViewModelTwo = ViewModelTwo()

var body: some View {
    List (
        ViewModelTwo.employeeData, id: \.age) { line in
            EmployeeCardView(employee: line)
        }
}
}
```

Comment: The compiler is complaining because it doesn't have a value for the properties (like birthdate) at the point that the initializer for `Employee` in `employeeData` is run. In this case, were are you hoping the value for `birthdate` and `newHireDate` will come from? Do you want to use the default `Date()` values you have in your initializer?

Comment: @jnpdx  I have a view which contains a Form wherein the user uses DatePickers to select their birthdate and newHireDate.  I would be happy with using a default Date() value, but would also like to learn how to set a different date for a default.

Comment: If you have form elements that should be providing these values, you need to pass references to those values when you want to use them. Right now, `employeeData` is just a static variable with no outside input. Maybe you really want to make it a function that takes those inputs?

Comment: @jnpdx My end goal is to display the employeeData in a List in EmployeeView.  I've added the EmployeeCardView and the EmployeeView to the original post to show where I want this data to be displayed.  That's why I'm using a static variable instead of a function.

Comment: But, again, you said that you wanted the data to come from a Form -- so having it `static` definitely doesn't make sense.

Comment: @jnpdx Fair point! Good catch. I’m trying to apply the concepts I learned in the apple developer tutorial for the sample Scrum app but also applying the Form user-input function. Perhaps there is a better way than the List approach.  I think List is best since there will be about 40 instances of Employee(age:,yearGroup:)

Comment: @jnpdx  Perhaps you have a suggestion for a func that could it into the List() code on my EmployeeView?

Comment: Why don't you create a function that updates `array`  on `ViewModelTwo` -- you have that property and you're not using it yet. Then, in your `List`, iterate over that.

Comment: @jnpdx Thank you!  That sounds like a winning solution.  I will give it my best effort...

Comment: static var is a global var independant of a class instance . So it can not be initialised using instance variables as these do not exist in the context of this static var.